# strlen() not working

Tags: c++

Basically, I'm passing a pointer to a character string into my constructor, which in turn initializes its base constructor when passing the string value in.  For some reason strlen() is not working, so it does not go into the right if statement.  I have checked to make sure that there is a value in the variable and there is.

Here is my code, I've taken out all the irrelevant parts:

Label class contents:

```
Label(int row, int column, const char *s, int length = 0) : LField(row, column, length, s, false)
{
}

Label (const Label &obj) : LField(obj)\
{
}

~Label()
{
}

Field *clone() const
{
    return new Label(*this);
}
```

LField class contents:

```
LField(int rowNumVal, int colNumVal, int widthVal, const char *valVal = "", bool canEditVal = true)
{ 
    if(strlen(valVal) > 0)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        //This is where it jumps to, even though the value in
        //valVal is 'SFields:'
        val = NULL;
    }
}

Field *clone() const
{
    return new LField(*this);
}

LField(const LField &clone) { 
    delete[] val;
    val = new char[strlen(clone.val) + 1]; 
    strcpy(val, clone.val);
    rowNum = clone.rowNum;
    colNum = clone.colNum;
    width = clone.width;
    canEdit = clone.canEdit;
    index = clone.index;
}
```

Screen class contents:

```
class Screen {
    Field *fields[50];
    int numOfFields;
    int currentField;
public:
    Screen()
    {
        numOfFields = 0;
        currentField = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        fields[i] = NULL;
    }


    ~Screen()
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            delete[] fields[i]; 
    }

    int add(const Field &obj)
    {
        int returnVal = 0;
        if (currentField < 50)
        {
            delete[] fields[currentField];
            fields[currentField] = obj.clone();   
            numOfFields += 1;   
            currentField += 1;      
            returnVal = numOfFields;    
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    Screen& operator+=(const Field &obj)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        temp = add(obj);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Main:

```
int main () {
    Screen s1;
    s1 += Label(3, 3, "SFields:");
}
```

Hopefully someone is able to see if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a problem with what you have posted. But I feel the details are missing which is most likely where the bug is hiding. Can you paste all the code? It's often the case that what you think the code is doing is not what in fact is happening, and the "irrelevant details" are the key to the mystery!

Comment: Yes, the bug is likely in the client code constructing Label. Make sure the string being passed in is null-terminated.

Comment: @stinky: Non null terminated would not result in 0 being returned by strlen.

Comment: I've inserted the rest of my code that is accessed during these calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcin at this point the problem will come down to debugging, I copied your code with some minor omissions and got the correct result.

Now it needs to be said, you should be using more C++ idiomatic code. For instance you should be using `std::string` instead of const char* and `std::vector` instead of your raw arrays.

Here is an example of what the LField constructor  would look like with `std::string`:

```
#include <string> // header for string

  LField(int rowNumVal, 
         int colNumVal, 
         int widthVal, 
         const std::string& valVal = "", 
         bool canEditVal = true)
  {
    std::cout << valVal;
      if(valVal.length() > 0)
      {
      }
      else
      {
          //This is where it jumps to, even though the value in
          //valVal is 'SFields:'
          //val = NULL;
      }
  }
```

Using these types will make your life considerably easier and if you make the change it may just fix your problem too.

PREVIOUS:
So you can be CERTAIN that the string is not being passed in correctly add a printline just before the strlen call. Once you do this work backward with printlines until you find where the string is not being set. This is a basic debugging technique.

```
Label(int row, 
            int column, 
            const char *s, 
            int length = 0) : 
                LField(row, column, length, s, false) {
  }

    LField(int rowNumVal, 
                     int colNumVal, 
                     int widthVal, 
                     const char *valVal = "", 
                     bool canEditVal = true) 
        { 
            std::cout << valVal << std::endl;
            if(strlen(valVal) > 0) 
            {

            }
            else {
                            //This is where it jumps to, even though the value in
                                                                    //valVal is 'SFields:'
                val = NULL;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I tried something like this and it does contain the value, but for some reason doesn't work with strlen :(

Comment: I'd go one step further and put the line:
std::cout << valVal << " " << strlen(valVal) << std::endl;
in the Label constructor. The chances that strlen is completely broken are exceptionally tiny as people do call it a few zillion times a day.

Any chance that you have defined your own version of strlen(), and it's getting called instead of the one from the standard library?

Comment: I ended up solving my problem, I'm really not sure exactly what I did to solve it, but all the posts here helped with ideas :)

Answer (score 3):

<LANGUAGE FEATURE XXXX IS BROKEN>! ... No, it isn't.

Just before measuring the string, write in a `puts(valVal)`, to ensure you are not mistaken about the contents of that variable.

Comment: Yep, I have done this, it does contain the value right before the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is strange behavior like this, memory getting screwed up is almost always the culprit.  Never mix **new** with **delete[]** OR **new[]** with **delete**. The latter is slightly worse than the former but they are both bad news. **delete[]** should only be used in conjunction with **new[]**.  Mixing these allocation/deallocation notations will result in undefined behavior.  Since you are never using **new[]**, replace all of your **delete[]** calls with **delete**.  It is also good practice and good manners to set your pointers to **NULL** after you delete them.  It is highly unlikely that you will be the only one debugging this code and it would be extremely annoying to debug your pointers thinking that there is valid memory there, when in fact there isn't.

Mixing these [notations](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) inevitably lead to [exploits](http://taossa.com/index.php/2007/01/03/attacking-delete-and-delete-in-c/) and [memory leaks](http://www.forteach.net/Programming/cplus/26557.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem here:

```
LField(const LField &clone) { 
    delete[] val;
    val = new char[strlen(clone.val) + 1];
```

val is uninitialized when the constructor is called, and you are deleting it.